# Bootstrap Button to Open Email

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, email

So I want to enable a button to open the default email sender on the user's computer (eg Outlook) so they can send us a direct email.

How can I do this with bootstrap buttons and what is the best way to keep bots away.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Just use a mailto link with the correct css style:

```
<a href="mailto:some@email.com" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Email Us</a>
```

Comment: What about bots? Dont really want to be spammed 24/7 Is there a way to distinguish them?

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking to hide the mailto in javascript. Like below. I think the mail has to be obfuscated in the javascript code as well.

Read more about [How to spamproof a mailto link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624667/how-to-spamproof-a-mailto-link)

**Not obfuscated example**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mailbutton').click(function(event) {
    window.location = "mailto:example@example.com";
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a href="#" id="mailbutton" class="btn btn-primary">Send us a mail!</a>
```